# Can I convert an ACCDB file to MDB with .NET

Tags: ms-access

Is there a way to convert an ACCDB Access database to MDB using .NET libraries or COM objects?

Thanks

Comment: Why is MDB satisfactory and ACCDB is not? The changes to the file format are pretty minor.

Comment: If you've been using user level security in mdb then the changes to the security mode are major. But I agree accdb is the future and if you need user level security then best to switch to a different product.

Comment: I've updated the question to be a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have a different take on it. Is there a way you can get SQL server to export both an ACCDB format and a MDB format? There must be an option in their export routine.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is if you have access to access 2007, you can export to a previous version, i.e. 2002-2003, this produces an mdb.

It's not programmatic, but it's better than nothing :)